# Mongodb shard zones for performance

Tags: mongodb

It has the following one-to-many relationship.
UserProfile - UserActivity,
UserProfile - UserItem,
UserProfile - ... ,
and so on.

Since there are many documents such as UserActivity and UserItem, collections are used instead of arrays.

As far as I know, even if the _id of the documents is the same, they are distributed and stored.

[Same shards across different MongoDB collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748038/same-shards-across-different-mongodb-collections)

What I'm curious about is whether using a shard zone to store documents of a specific user in one shard and access them as transaction is faster than distributed transaction. Both read and write.
(Shards are physically close)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-shards/

Comment: Are you concerned about read or write performance?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
Yes.

Comment: I mean, are you mainly concerned in write performance or are you mainly concerned in read performance?

Comment: Oh, I got you.
I wrote again the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to [Sharding Query Pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#sharding-query-patterns):

> The ideal shard key distributes data evenly across the sharded cluster while also facilitating common query patterns. When you choose a shard key, consider your most common query patterns and whether a given shard key covers them.
>
> In a sharded cluster, the mongos routes queries to only the shards that contain the relevant data if the queries contain the shard key. When the queries do not contain the shard key, the queries are broadcast to all shards for evaluation. These types of queries are called scatter-gather queries. Queries that involve multiple shards for each request are less efficient and do not scale linearly when more shards are added to the cluster.
>
> This does not apply for aggregation queries that operate on a large amount of data. In these cases, scatter-gather can be a useful approach that allows the query to run in parallel on all shards.

See also [Zones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/#zones):

> Some common deployment patterns where zones can be applied are as follows:
>
> - Isolate a specific subset of data on a specific set of shards. (Maybe enforced by some data protection laws)
> - Ensure that the most relevant data reside on shards that are geographically closest to the application servers.
> - Route data to shards based on the hardware / performance of the shard hardware.

Your question does not provide sufficient information whether any of above applies in your case.